# Normalization python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to normalize a numpy array but I'm not getting the expected values( from 0 to 1).

Here how I approached the problem:

Suppose `a` is a numpy array

```
result = a - np.mean(a) /  np.sqrt(np.sum((a-np.mean(a) ** 2) / (len(a)-1)
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2):

Normalization doesn't mean you get values from 0 to 1, it just adjusts scales to comparable magnitudes and/or removes bias. If you want to normalize to the 0-1 range you have to subtract `np.min(a)` and divide by `np.max(a)-np.min(a)`.

```
a = (a - np.min(a))/(np.max(a)-np.min(a))
```

See this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/how-to-normalize-data-to-0-1-range

Comment: thanks for your answer as well as the link

Comment: If it helped you can upvote and/or accept the answer :)